# JQuery scroll event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have been trying to make jquery scroll text in a textbox using a button click but it does not work in IE, Chrome, or Firefox.

I would like my textbox manually to scroll down on click of the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://localhost:62240/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        x = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div").scroll(function () {
                $("span").text(x += 1);
            });
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("div").scroll();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Try the scrollbar in the div</p>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;overflow:scroll;">
        In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
        <br><br>
        'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
    </div>
    <p>Scrolled <span>0</span> times.</p>
    <button>Trigger scroll event for the window</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z9jU6/)

Comment: try with: $("div").on("scroll",function(

Comment: I think you kinda misunderstood the `.scroll()` functionality: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Are you expecting `$("div").scroll()` to cause the div contents to move, i.e. scroll?

Comment: I guess you are looking for the scrollTo() function in Jquery

Comment: This is not complete, but maybe it will give you a hint?
You need to add logic for scrolling up... http://jsfiddle.net/joseftw/QzMP9/4/

Answer (score 2):

scroll() is the event fired when div is scrolled. If you want to scroll by clicking on the button, try this instead:

```
    x = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $('div').animate({ scrollTop: (x+1)*20 }, 200);
            $("span").text(x += 1);
        });
    });
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/339j5/3/)

Comment: On the first button click it doesn't scroll.

Comment: Yes, I've just fixed it. As the first click it was scrolling to 0*20, it didn't move...

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery import doesn't work. If you take the exact same code, paste it into a jsfiddle with jquery imported by them, and then click the button, the span counter increments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code from @lpg fixed to make everything work properly(sorry I write this as an answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment yet):

```js
    x = 0;
    height = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            height = $('div').scrollTop();
            $('div').animate({ scrollTop: height+20 }, 200);
        });
        $('div').scroll(function() {
            $("span").text(x += 1);
        });
    });
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davl3232/9N3B4/) fixed.

The jQuery method `element.scrollTop();` is used to get the scroll position of a scrollable element, and also to set it when an argument is included. Then `$('div').scrollTop();` returns the pixels scrolled inside the div from its top, and `$('div').scrollTop(20);` will scroll the div 20 pixels from its top.